# Get width of object from library (AS3)

Tags: actionscript-3, object, actionscript

How to get width and height object in library in Actionscript 3?

Comment: At runtime or at design time?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get width and height of a library asset during runtime, you need to create an instance of it, add it to stage, and then query `getRect()` or `getBounds()` of the created instance. If you don't need that instance right now, just remove it from stage.

```
var temp:DisplayObject=new YourLibraryAsset();
stage.addChild(temp); 
var r:Rectangle=temp.getRect(stage);
stage.removeChild(temp);
```

This does not work if the current class does not have an access to stage.

Answer (score 0):

To get width and height of a library asset during runtime, you need to create an instance of it, and grab the width/height. (no need to add it to the stage)

```
import flash.display.MovieClip;

var symbol:MovieClip = new Symbol1();
trace(symbol.width, symbol.height);
```

Comment: I've tried this, and received zeroes for some reason. The only remedy was making it reach the stage.

Comment: @Vesper Thats because the "draw" method does not get called unless the object is on stage.